# Determine all sites with active script editors

Tags: content-editor-web-part, script, team-sites, cewp

Can somebody help me to determine all the sites which have content editor web parts active on the SharePoint Farm? Both publishing and non publishing sites. Is there a script?

I found one at [Finding CEWP’s with script in your SharePoint sites](http://blog.kuppens-switsers.net/sharepoint/finding-cewps-with-script-in-your-sharepoint-sites/). But this one is not giving me the complete list. I guess it is only listing out the publishing sites

Answer (score 0):

The script is returning results from both publishing sites and other sites. But it only returns CEWP's which have script tags in it or CEWP's which has a contentlink that point to a textfile with scripts. If you want all CEWP's, you need to adapt the Get-CEWP function. Replace the following code:

```
if ($webPart.ContentLink.Length -gt 0)
{
    # Check file in ContentLink for script tags
    $file = $web.GetFile($webPart.ContentLink)
    $data = $file.OpenBinary()
    $encode = New-Object System.Text.ASCIIEncoding
    $contents = $encode.GetString($data)
    if ($contents.ToLower().Contains("<script>"))
    {
        Write-Output "$($web.Url)/$url (CONTENTLINK)"
    }
    break
}
if ($webPart.Content.InnerText.Contains("<script>"))
{
    Write-Output "$($web.Url)/$url (HTML)"
}
```

with:

```
Write-Output "$($web.Url)/$url"
```

Then the function will return all CEWP webparts and not only those with script in them.